# Your connection is not secure

Tags: configuration, https

I am trying to setup a .onion address to point to my https site. Every time I try to access it from the .onion address I get a warning in Tor browser:

> Your connection is not secure. The owner of myonionaddress.onion has
>   configured their website improperly. To protect your information from
>   being stolen, Tor Browser has not connected to this website.

.

Other .onion sites (facebook's, duckduckgo's, etc.) load fine and don't have a warning...just mine. What am I doing wrong?

My config:

```
HiddenServiceDir /home/user/onion_folder
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 443 187.485.887.28:443
```

running version 0.3.4.9

Comment: Your certificate is valid for _whatever_.onion, right? What SSL error does it give you?